# Aligning two molecules in XYZ format, before v12.3

Tags: graphics3d, visualization, chemistry, version-12

I have two molecules in [`"XYZ"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XYZ.html) format and I want to align them.

As I am using *Mathematica* version 12.0, which does not have this [`MoleculeAlign`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculeAlign.html) function (Introduced in v12.3) I am looking for alternatives.

Here are the molecules [B1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5k8z6ilzrw6vi86/B1.xyz?dl=0) and [C1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j5bcpwbpx044if/C1.xyz?dl=0)

```
c1 = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j5bcpwbpx044if/C1.xyz?dl=1", "XYZ"];
b1 = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/5k8z6ilzrw6vi86/B1.xyz?dl=1", "XYZ"];
```

Comment: You could try aligning them in the Cloud version, which does have `MoleculeAlign[]`. Otherwise, you're effectively asking people to re-implement something nontrivial on your behalf, when you haven't even made an attempt of your own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am able to do it in the Cloud version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Build your own

I can't personally test this in V12, however, the functions I use were introduced in v12, and the OP report this works fine for them.

I extract the coordinates using [`MoleculeValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculeValue.html)`[m1, "AtomCoordinates"]`, centre the first molecule, and then [`FindGeometricTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html) with the option [`TransformationClass`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationClass.html)`->"Rigid"` to rotate and translate the second into the first.

```
simpleAlignMol[m1_,m2_]:=Block[
    {cm1,cm2, tcm1, tcm2, transform, tm1, tm2},
    cm1 =  QuantityMagnitude[MoleculeValue[m1, "AtomCoordinates"], "Angstroms"]; (* Coordinates molecule 1 *)
    cm2 =  QuantityMagnitude[MoleculeValue[m2, "AtomCoordinates"], "Angstroms"]; (* Coordinates molecule 2 *)

    tcm1 = TranslationTransform[-Mean[cm1]][Normal@cm1]; (* Centered coordinates molecule 1 *)
    transform = Last@FindGeometricTransform[tcm1,cm2, TransformationClass->"Rigid"]; (* Rotate+Translate Transformation *)
    tcm2 = transform[cm2]; (* Aligned coordinates molecule 2 *)
    (* Molecules with updated coordinates *)
    tm1 = Molecule[m1, AtomCoordinates-> Quantity[tcm1,"Angstroms"] ];
    tm2 = Molecule[m2, AtomCoordinates-> Quantity[tcm2,"Angstroms"] ];

    {tm1,tm2}
]

Show[MoleculePlot3D/@simpleAlignMol[c1,b1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. This code is working in V12.

Answer (score 3):

## Do it in a free kernel V13

This was tested in [`$Version`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Version.html)

Cloud:

> 13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)

[Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) (free):

> 13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 10, 2021)

So this works even if you don't have a license for Mathematica V12.3 or above

```
c1 = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j5bcpwbpx044if/C1.xyz?dl=1", "XYZ"];
b1 = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/5k8z6ilzrw6vi86/B1.xyz?dl=1", "XYZ"];
```

Before aligning

```
Show @@ MoleculePlot3D[{c1, b1}]
```

[image]

Aligned

```
Apply[Show,MoleculePlot3D/@{MoleculeAlign[c1,b1],c1}]
```

[image]